# Why does table overlap border of parent div element?

Tags: html

In the following example - http://jsfiddle.net/v4CdY/2/ the table crosses bottom border of the parent div element. This happens when the table has align="left" attribute. If you remove this attribute the table will be properly nested inside of the div element. Why?

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px 16px;">
  <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Comment: Note that in html5, which I hope you are using, the align attribute (among others) is obsolete http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html You should only use CSS for styling, that's what CSS is for...

Comment: This table and align attribute are created by CKEditor. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because by default the `align="left"` adds `float: left;` to the table, if you add `float: none;` to the table or use `table { text-align: left; }` instead of the `align` attribute you'll have no such problem...

[**<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/GjKY8/)